# How to use GenJavaDoc plugin for sbt?

Tags: java, sbt, javadoc

I have a very basic sbt project, all scala code except for one `.java` file, for which I need to generate a standard javadoc webpage.

I'm trying to follow the instructions on [the plugin's README](https://github.com/typesafehub/genjavadoc/blob/master/README.md).  I've copied all the code following "Integration into an SBT build is quite simple," which defines  variables`JavaDoc` and `javadocSettings`, into my `build.sbt` file, and also added the following:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

autoCompilerPlugins := true
```

The instructions say I must "Add[] `javadocSettings` to a `Project`."  I don't know what that means.  Is that what the code in the README does, or is it something separate I need to do?  If so, how?

In any event, the README continues: "the JavaDoc can be generated using `genjavadoc:doc`."  Yet, in `sbt` I see:

```
> genjavadoc:doc
[error] No such setting/task
[error] genjavadoc:doc
[error]               ^
>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a configuration as it is described in the `README.md` of the plugin. Your task invocation is not working, because there is no `genjavadoc` normally in sbt.

You have to add it as documented in the plugin documentation. In your `build.sbt` file add following content recommended by the plugin (leaving what you have already):

```
lazy val JavaDoc = config("genjavadoc") extend Compile

lazy val javadocSettings = inConfig(JavaDoc)(Defaults.configSettings) ++ Seq(
  libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin("com.typesafe.genjavadoc" %% "genjavadoc-plugin" % "0.7" cross CrossVersion.full),
  scalacOptions <+= target map (t => "-P:genjavadoc:out=" + (t / "java")),
  packageDoc in Compile <<= packageDoc in JavaDoc,
  sources in JavaDoc <<= (target, compile in Compile, sources in Compile) map ((t, c, s) =>
      (t / "java" ** "*.java").get ++ s.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".java"))),
  javacOptions in JavaDoc := Seq(),
  artifactName in packageDoc in JavaDoc :=
    ((sv, mod, art) => "" + mod.name + "_" + sv.binary + "-" + mod.revision + "-javadoc.jar")
)
```

However to make it work you need to add the config and the settings to the project. The easiest way is to add in your `build.sbt` one extra line:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).configs(JavaDoc).settings(javadocSettings: _*)
```

Now you should be able to generate javadoc using `genjavadoc:doc`.

Given the above, the complete `build.sbt` could look like this:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).configs(JavaDoc).settings(javadocSettings: _*)

lazy val JavaDoc = config("genjavadoc") extend Compile

lazy val javadocSettings = inConfig(JavaDoc)(Defaults.configSettings) ++ Seq(
  libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin("com.typesafe.genjavadoc" %% "genjavadoc-plugin" % "0.7" cross CrossVersion.full),
  scalacOptions <+= target map (t => "-P:genjavadoc:out=" + (t / "java")),
  packageDoc in Compile <<= packageDoc in JavaDoc,
  sources in JavaDoc <<= (target, compile in Compile, sources in Compile) map ((t, c, s) =>
      (t / "java" ** "*.java").get ++ s.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".java"))),
  javacOptions in JavaDoc := Seq(),
  artifactName in packageDoc in JavaDoc :=
    ((sv, mod, art) => "" + mod.name + "_" + sv.binary + "-" + mod.revision + "-javadoc.jar")
)
```

PS. Small bonus, if you're using an sbt newer than 0.13.2, you can define `javadocSettings` without using `<<=` and `<+=` and other similar operators like this:

```
lazy val javadocSettings = inConfig(JavaDoc)(Defaults.configSettings) ++ Seq(
  addCompilerPlugin("com.typesafe.genjavadoc" %% "genjavadoc-plugin" % "0.7" cross CrossVersion.full),
  scalacOptions += s"-P:genjavadoc:out=${target.value}/java",
  packageDoc in Compile := (packageDoc in JavaDoc).value,
  sources in JavaDoc := 
    (target.value / "java" ** "*.java").get ++ (sources in Compile).value.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".java")),
  javacOptions in JavaDoc := Seq(),
  artifactName in packageDoc in JavaDoc :=
    ((sv, mod, art) => "" + mod.name + "_" + sv.binary + "-" + mod.revision + "-javadoc.jar")
)
```

Comment: Works, thanks!  This would go great in the plugin's README file.

Comment: @AdamMackler I think if you feel so, you should do a pull request ;)

Comment: Also, the `autoCompilerPlugins := true` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @AdamMackler I've removed `autoCompilerPlugins := true` as you've suggested from the answer, thx.